# Error importing gspread in iPython Notebook

Tags: python, ipython, pycharm, gspread

So I have an iPython notebook setup in Pycharm and am getting the "ImportError: No module named gspread" error thrown when I run:

```
import gspread
```

I'm running this inside a virtualenv that I have verified in PyCharm is the one being used. I pip installed gspread. I tested that I can import other modules (i.e. numpy) without issue. From the iPython command line I do not get the error when importing gspread, it is only when running it inside the iPython notebook on Pycharm.

Any idea what might be the issue? I'm stumped.

Comment: Have you already checked that `site.getsitepackages()` returns the same list of paths to `sitepackage directories` in both cases?